# Database columns exclusive or relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

In my project it would come in handy to put two boolean columns of a table in an 'exclusice or' like relationship, is that somehow possible in laravel? FYI: I use mysql as a driver if that matters.

Comment: What is your endgoal? To differentiate different models in a record?

Comment: For my use case it would really make no sense if both of these where true. Or do just have to check for this case and handle it when I alter the bool columns?

Comment: So , you simply mean that they couldn't both be the same value?

Comment: You are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [CHECK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) constraint can be used to check specific requirements for a table row. This logic be placed inside the `up` function of a [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#introduction).

```
public function up ()
{
    Schema::create('order', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->boolean('in_transit');
        $table->boolean('is_delivered');
    });

    // Add the constraint
    DB::statement('ALTER TABLE order ADD CONSTRAINT chk_delivery CHECK ((in_transit AND NOT is_delivered) OR (is_delivered AND NOT in_transit));');
}
```